# Yii2, связи многие ко многим

Tags: yii2

Добрый день! Я уже не один раз читал тут темы, пользовался поиском по интересующей меня теме в Yii2. А именно связь многие ко многим. Имеется три таблицы: продукты(id, title, price)- у одного продукта может быть много категорий, категории(id, title)- у одной категории может быть много продуктов, и связующая таблица(id_product, id_title).Делал миграции при помощи инструмента gii, потом делал модели, он мне посвязывал все в связи, но какой в этом смысл если я в них не шарю. Вот решил разобраться. Читал основную документацию. 
Нашел похожий пример: таблица Articles с полем id, таблица ArticlesTags с полями id, articlesid, tagsid, таблица tags с полем id. И связь которая там была

```
    public function getTags()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['ID' => 'TagsID'])
     ->viaTable(Articlestags::tableName(), ['ArticlesID' => 'ID']);
     }
```

Попытался применить к моему заданию получилось так. 
Связь для категорий (находится в модели product)
     `public function getCategory()
      {
      return $this->hasMany(Category::className(['id'=>'category_id'])->viaTable(CategoryProduct::tableName(),['product_id'=>'id']);}`
            Связь для продуктов (находится в модели category)

```
 public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['id'=>'product_id'])->viaTable(CategoryProduct::tableName(),['category_id'=>'id']);
}
```

И последнее пытаюсь вызвать категории так  `$product = Product::findOne($id);
        $categories = $product->getCategory();`

Прошу помощи где не правильно что, может чтото с viaTable() -пытаюсь разобраться с этим, чтоб самому легко решать подобные задачи. Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу!

Answer (score 0):

$categories = $product->category
либо $categories = $product->getCategory()->all()
Реляция возвращает ActiveQuery